# How to find a value in a python dataframe using a key and summing it with another value in another df with another key

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4']})
df1['%'] = 0.5
print(df1)
  ISIN    %
0   A1  0.5
1   B2  0.5
2   C3  0.5
3   D4  0.5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['C3', 'D4', 'E5', 'F6']})
df2['%'] = 0.2
print(df2)
  ISIN    %
0   C3  0.2
1   D4  0.2
2   E5  0.2
3   F6  0.2
```

I would like the keys (ISIN) to check if they match in the two dataframes, and if they do match then to add the % from df2 to df1. Therefore desired output would be:

```
print(df1)
  ISIN    %
0   A1  0.5
1   B2  0.5
2   C3  0.7
3   D4  0.7
```

I have tried the following code but python doesn't seem to like a For loop for this as there are two dataframes. There is no error, it's just the summation doesn't happen:

```
for row in df1['ISIN']:
    if df1['ISIN'].isin(df2['ISIN']) is True:
        df1.loc[row, '%'] = df1.loc[row, '%']+df2.loc[row,'%']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `map`:

```
In [32]:
df1['%'] = (df1['%'] + df1['ISIN'].map(df2.set_index('ISIN')['%'])).fillna(df1['%'])
df1

Out[32]:
  ISIN    %
0   A1  0.5
1   B2  0.5
2   C3  0.7
3   D4  0.7
```

Comment: It works but there is an error indicating a value is being assigned to a copy of a slice of a dataframe:

"SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: It's likely it's something you're doing prior to this, you'll need to post more code

Answer (score 1):

I like Ed's one liner.

This is an alternative solution that is more explicit.  First you merge df2, then add the two columns.  Finally, you cleanup by dropping the merged column.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='ISIN', suffixes=('', '_df2'))
>>> df1
  ISIN    %  %_df2
0   A1  0.5    NaN
1   B2  0.5    NaN
2   C3  0.5    0.2
3   D4  0.5    0.2

mask = df1['%_df2'].isnull()
df1.loc[~mask, '%'] += df1.loc[~mask, '%_df2']
del df1['%_df2']

>>> df1
  ISIN    %
0   A1  0.5
1   B2  0.5
2   C3  0.7
3   D4  0.7
```